# How to extract data from HTML tag with specific attribute and value using regex in C#

Tags: c#, html, regex, attributes, tags

I have been trying to extract a single value from some HTML data, but I haven't been able to focus on exactly the piece I am looking for:

The line I am trying to read from is:

```
<span class="temp">5</span>
```

There are many other "span" tags with different classes, so I need to only accept "temp" class,
and then get the value?

I really have no experience with Regex, but have been trying to figure it out.
Here are just some of the lines I have tried:

```
//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"<span class=""temp"">(.+?)<", RegexOptions.None);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"<span class=""temp"">\s*(.+?)\s*</span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"<span class=""temp""> (.*?) </span> ", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"<span class=""temp"">(([^<]|<[^\/]|<\/[^s]|<\/s[^p]|<\/sp[^a]|<\/spa[^n]|<\/span[^ \t >])*)</span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"<span class=""temp"">\s*([^<])\s*</span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"<span class=""temp"">\s*(<.*?>) * ([^<] *)\s*</span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"(?<=<span\s *class=""temp""[^><]*>\s*)[^<>]*", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"(?<=<span\s*class=""temp""[^><]*>\s*)[^<>]*", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"(?<=<span\s*class=""temp"">\s*)*", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"<span[^>] *> (.*?) </ span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"<span class=""temp""></span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//MatchCollection data = Regex.Matches(searchData, @"<span class=""temp""></span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!
Doug

Comment: Have you tried this one `@"<span class=""temp"">[^<>]*</span>"`?

Comment: [Dont' parse html with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5762332)

Comment: Hi gilmutdinov, unfortunately that did not work either....

Comment: Hi Magnetron, Thank you got it. I will find anther way to extract what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find all elements you need using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes) with XPATH expression:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
    
// select all <span> elements with class 'temp' containing text and no element children
var xpath = "//span[contains(@class, 'temp') and text() and not(*)]";
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```